# NullPointerException Android error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

**Ok guys, i have made a quiz test and here is the main quiz activity class.**

```
public class startGame extends Activity {

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    CountDownTimer C1,C2;
    MediaPlayer mp2,mp3;
    int y = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startgame);

        final Button r1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        final Button r2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        final Button r3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
        r1.setClickable(false);
        r2.setClickable(false);
        r3.setClickable(false);  
        anakatema();

        AdView ad = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct);
        mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wrong);


        final TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myIVText2);
        C1 = new CountDownTimer(31000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textic.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            textic.setText("0");
            if ("1".equals(myMenu.k)) { r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}
            if ("2".equals(myMenu.k)) { r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}
            if ("3".equals(myMenu.k)) { r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}
            myMenu.lives = myMenu.lives - 1;
            myMenu.streak = 0;
            myMenu.k = checkFinish();
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            textic.setText("Oraios!");
        }       

        }.start();  

        myMenu.k = checkFinish();

        r1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r1.setClickable(false);
                r2.setClickable(false);
                r3.setClickable(false);
                y=0;
                if ("1".equals(myMenu.k)) {
                    r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);
                    myMenu.score = myMenu.score + 10;
                    myMenu.streak = myMenu.streak + 1;
                    if ("on".equals(myMenu.sound)) {mp2.start();}
                }
                else {
                    r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneowrong);
                    if ("2".equals(myMenu.k)) { r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}
                    if ("3".equals(myMenu.k)) { r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}
                    myMenu.lives = myMenu.lives - 1;
                    myMenu.streak = 0;
                    if ("on".equals(myMenu.sound)) {mp3.start();}
                }
                C1.cancel();
                myMenu.k = checkFinish();
            }
        });

        r2.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r1.setClickable(false);
                r2.setClickable(false);
                r3.setClickable(false);
                y=0;
                if ("2".equals(myMenu.k)) {
                    r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);
                    myMenu.score = myMenu.score + 10;
                    myMenu.streak = myMenu.streak + 1;
                    if ("on".equals(myMenu.sound)) {mp2.start();}
                }
                else {
                    r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneowrong);
                    if ("1".equals(myMenu.k)) { r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}
                    if ("3".equals(myMenu.k)) { r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}                 
                    myMenu.lives = myMenu.lives - 1;
                    myMenu.streak = 0;
                    if ("on".equals(myMenu.sound)) {mp3.start();}
                }
                C1.cancel();
                myMenu.k = checkFinish();
            }
        });

        r3.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r1.setClickable(false);
                r2.setClickable(false);
                r3.setClickable(false);
                y=0;
                if ("3".equals(myMenu.k)) {
                    r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);
                    myMenu.score = myMenu.score + 10;
                    myMenu.streak = myMenu.streak + 1;
                    if ("on".equals(myMenu.sound)) {mp2.start();}
                }
                else {
                    r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneowrong);
                    if ("1".equals(myMenu.k)) { r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}
                    if ("2".equals(myMenu.k)) { r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);}                 
                    myMenu.lives = myMenu.lives - 1;
                    myMenu.streak = 0;
                    if ("on".equals(myMenu.sound)) {mp3.start();}
                }
                C1.cancel();
                myMenu.k = checkFinish();
            }
        });

    }

    public String checkFinish() {

        String h="";
        final AnyDBAdapter eventsData = new AnyDBAdapter(getBaseContext());
        myMenu.question = myMenu.question + 1;
        if (myMenu.streak == 5) {
            myMenu.lives = myMenu.lives + 1;
        }

        String qq = ""+list.get(0);
        nextQ();

        eventsData.open();
        final Cursor c = eventsData.ExampleSelect(qq);
        this.startManagingCursor(c);
        eventsData.close();
        h = c.getString(5);
        C2 = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 if (myMenu.lives != -1) {
                    Button r1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
                    r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneo);
                    Button r2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
                    r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneo);
                    Button r3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
                    r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneo);
                    setQuestions(c);
                    c.close();
                    C2.cancel();
                    r1.setClickable(true);
                    r2.setClickable(true);
                    r3.setClickable(true);
                    y = 1;
                 }
             }
          }.start();

        C1.start();
        if (myMenu.lives == -1) {
            C1.cancel();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent("dv.qtestgr.dvyzual.QuizTestActivity.ENDQUIZGAME"));
        }
        return h;
    }

    private void anakatema() {
        int count = getTotalQuestions();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);      
    }

    private int getTotalQuestions() {
        final AnyDBAdapter eventsData = new AnyDBAdapter(getBaseContext());
        eventsData.open();
        Cursor c = eventsData.countQuestions();
        this.startManagingCursor(c);
        String h = c.getString(0);
        c.close();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(h);
        eventsData.close();
        return n;
    }

    private void nextQ() {
        list.remove(0);
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            anakatema();
        }
    }

    private void setQuestions(Cursor c) {
        TextView rscore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q1);
        rscore.setText("Σκορ: " + myMenu.score + " Ερώτηση: " + myMenu.question);
        TextView rlifes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myIVText);
        rlifes.setText("" + myMenu.lives + "");
        TextView r0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        r0.setText(c.getString(1));
        Button r1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        r1.setText(c.getString(2));
        Button r2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        r2.setText(c.getString(3));
        Button r3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
        r3.setText(c.getString(4));
    } 

    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
  {  
         //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
         if (y==0){
             return true;
         }
         if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
         {  

           C1.cancel();
           C2.cancel();
           finish();

         }  
         return true;  
   }

}
```

**It's working fine but after game ends, and start it for some more times, i have that  errors:**

```
03-31 23:42:47.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1519): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at dv.qtestgr.dvyzual.startGame$4.onClick(startGame.java:139)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-31 23:42:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**How i can find the mistake? I believe it's something with variable initialization but i am a little blind to find it**

Comment: First: do you see how much redundant code you have in your application. Second: Can you highlight or put some indication to the line where the exception is hitting. I can see its line 139, but I am not willing to count to line 139. 
 `at dv.qtestgr.dvyzual.startGame$4.onClick(startGame.java:139)`

Comment: thx i think i just solved, it was the mediaplayer that i always forget to .release(); when activity ends. And yes my code is a bit complicated as i am new in android develepment ^^ at about 139 line i called the mp2.start so you are right

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change this :

```
String qq = ""+list.get(0);
```

to this:

```
String qq = "";
if(!list.isEmpty()){
    qq += list.get(0);
}
```

and also, change this :

```
private void nextQ() {
    list.remove(0);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        anakatema();
    }
}
```

to this:

```
private void nextQ() {
    if(!list.isEmpty()){
        list.remove(0);
    } else {
        anakatema();
    }
}
```

I'd like to know the result ;)

Comment: Line 3 of the logcat says that the exception occurs in onClick()

Comment: dv.qtestgr.dvyzual.startGame$4.onClick(startGame.java:139) says error from line 139 which is `nextQ();` , line 139 is inside method checkFinish(), which is called in the last line of method onClick(). If my solution doesn't really work, my last guess would be existance of a problem in method anakatema(). I got a -1, therefore no motivation to look further.

Comment: well problem was that i didn't .release(); my mediaplayer files ^^ your comments were nice but i didn't post the starting package .... and imports, so if you counted to 139 it was wrong count hehe

Answer (score 0):

Your `Button`s r1, r2, and r3 are defined in `onCreate()`, and therefore their scope is limited to the method. Define them as fields and the code should work.

Comment: didn't work, think it has to do with mediaplayer as i dont release the music. in console before that red errors, i have a blue error for mediaplayer

Comment: what does line 139 say? I'm simply guessing because I don't have line numbers

Comment: it was mediaplayer start, and as i forgot to .release when activity ends it cause that error. at least i solved it thanks ;)